# Lag In Singleplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Now anyone who has played Minecraft multiplayer would know that occasionally, the ***server*** will have a stutter, and no containers (chests, furnaces) etc. can be opened, along with all commands and chat become non-responsive. Today I got onto my singleplayer map world, and continued to work, but I started to experience lag. By lag i do not mean FPS lag, I run a solid 300 constantly. This seemed like server lag on singleplayer, which was confusing. I googled it and found the answer was allocating more RAM. I have 32 GB, and 16 allocated however. Is there anything else tat could cause this?

Comment: Do you mean you already have that RAM allocated when you experienced the lag? Are you using any mods or command blocks?

Comment: @colorfusion Already hgave 16GB allocated, and no mods, lots of command blocks

Comment: That much RAM allocated can cause lag, I'd recommend a max of 2GB. The command blocks are also likely a cause of the lag, depending on what they're doing. Could you paste the commands, or upload your world?

Comment: @colorfusion world can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/v64cvhn65p6i87w/by_oBlazin.rar)

Comment: Mainly, it looks like you need to get rid of all your `/setblock` clocks (E.G: [1](http://i.imgur.com/V6CDXdM.jpg), [2](http://i.imgur.com/Ddrx3oX.jpg), [3](http://i.imgur.com/U2ATiqb.jpg)). They're causing a huge amount of lag from particles and block updates, and can easily be replaced with the new repeating command blocks. [Using traditional redstone (pistons, repeaters) for command blocks](http://i.imgur.com/3SUK1Vz.jpg) is also generally a bad idea; try make it all command blocks to minimize lag.

Comment: I only had 1 redstone block clock left, dont think that would cause too much?

Comment: Is the world you uploaded up to date? The images I linked in my comment show where I found at least 13 setblock clocks in the world. Lag accumulates from different things, so you should try to get rid of it wherever possible.

Comment: Oh yea sorry old map, I had removed redstone block clocks, nothing new added, but still lag @colorfusion

Comment: Changed allocated RAM to 2GB and replaced all the redstone stuff?

Comment: yes @colorfusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the cause of lag in my singleplayer world in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/367062/how-can-i-find-the-cause-of-lag-in-my-singleplayer-world-in-minecraft)

Comment: Closed as a duplicate (community tried multiple times it seems, but both cases aged away). https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/322054 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/322507

Answer (score 2):

Is /gamerule randomTickSpeed high? Normally it's at 3, and it caused the same kind of lag for me after I tried changing it to 5000.

Comment: Again I ask, did this solve the problem of lag?